# Explanation for remove_filter used in the below code

Tags: filters, post-meta, actions

I am very confused about what the developer has done here. This is inside a class..a filter has been added and then removed, added again. This code results in many errors as well.

```
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), -1, 4);
```

and the callback function

```
public static function get_post_metadata($meta_value, $post_id, $meta_key, $single){
        if (is_admin()){
            return null;
        }

        remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);
        $child_meta = get_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, false);
        $meta=null;
        if (WPKWP::get_parent()){
            $parent_meta = get_metadata('post', WPKWP::get_parent(), $meta_key, false);

            if (is_array($parent_meta) && is_array($child_meta)) {
                $meta = array_merge($parent_meta, $child_meta);
            } else {
                $meta = $parent_meta;
            }
        } else {
            $meta = $child_meta;
        }
        add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);
        return $meta;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remove_filter()` is necessary to avoid the callback from being called recursively, which would result in a memory issue due to a never-ending function execution.

And that recursion could happen because the callback is hooked to [`get_post_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_meta_type_metadata/) which is invoked via the [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) function which the callback calls.

So you need to first "unhook"/unregister the callback from the hook and only then you may call `get_metadata()`.

Otherwise, you'd end up with something like:

```
WP applies the filter (calls apply_filters( 'get_post_metadata', ... ))
- your callback is called
- the callback calls get_metadata()
- WP applies the filter
  - your callback is called
  - the callback calls get_metadata()
  - WP applies the filter
      - your callback is called
      - the callback calls get_metadata()
      - WP applies the filter.....
```

Or:

```php
your_callback() {
  your_callback() {
    your_callback() {
      your_callback() {
        ..... it never ends ...
```

So your code is good in that it's avoiding the unwanted recursion.

However, I noticed that you're not properly removing the filter:

```php
// You added the filter like so:
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), -1, 4);

// Then in the callback, you're removing it like this:
remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);

// And later in that callback, the filter is added back:
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);
```

And the problem is, when removing a filter/action, the priority *and* number of accepted parameters must match the same values you used when adding the filter:

```php
// If you added the filter like so:
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), -1, 4);

// Then use the same parameters when removing the filter:
remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), -1, 4);

// And not like this — priority should be -1 and this is missing the fourth parameter:
remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);
```

And if you initially added the filter like so, then you should also add it back *inside the callback* the same way — using the same parameters:

```php
// Like this:
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), -1, 4);

// Not this: (priority doesn't match)
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);
```

Comment: thanks ! if the filter is removed then how add_filter can work?

Comment: Sorry, quite busy lately -_- So it works because the callback (the class method) unregisters itself (via `remove_filter()`) by the time that WP applies the filter and calls the callback. And later it registers itself back (via `add_filter()`). These steps are going to be repeated every time WP applies the filter (or that the callback gets called): filter applied → callback called → callback unregisters itself (remove filter) → callback registers itself back (re-add filter).

Comment: all clear thank you :)

Comment: the errors were happening because add_filter was added before returning. Problems went off after I placed it after the return.

Comment: Not sure about your last comment... but anyway, I had a time today to write a better answer, so I updated the answer and I hope it's more helpful now (despite I didn't include that "how add_filter can work" part). :)